# How to find object by name from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I’m calling json –file from the url with code below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: wsUrl,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(data1)  {
    aika = data1.weatherStations[0].measuredTime;
    ilma = data1.weatherStations[0].sensorValues[0].sensorValue;
    tie = data1.weatherStations[0].sensorValues[2].sensorValue;

                 },
    error: function()  {
      alert ("Error message.");
            }
});
```

Url to file is dynamic and the result files are not identical (please see the samples)

[JSON 1](https://tie.digitraffic.fi/api/v1/data/weather-data/2050)
[JSON 2](https://tie.digitraffic.fi/api/v1/data/weather-data/8037)

It seems that in every case sensorValues[ 0] returns air temperature and sensorValues[ 2] road temperature. But if I want to call e.g. wind direction, I don’t know the number of sensorValues, but I know that the “Id” for wind direction is allways the same.  How do I call sensorValue by Id?
I can’t edit the json –files.

Comment: Thank you, all the answers were helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use JS [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var json = {
  "dataUpdatedTime" : "2017-07-11T15:47:00+03:00",
  "weatherStations" : [ {
    "id" : 2050,
    "measuredTime" : "2017-07-11T15:44:00+03:00",
    "sensorValues" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "ILMA",
      "oldName" : "airtemperature1",
      "shortName" : "Ilma ",
      "sensorValue" : 18.2,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 2,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "ILMA_DERIVAATTA",
      "oldName" : "airtemperature1change",
      "shortName" : "DIlm",
      "sensorValue" : 0.2,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C/h"
    }, {
      "id" : 3,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TIE_1",
      "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature1",
      "shortName" : "Tie1 ",
      "sensorValue" : 20.5,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 4,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TIE_1_DERIVAATTA",
      "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature1change",
      "shortName" : "DTie1",
      "sensorValue" : -0.2,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C/h"
    }, {
      "id" : 5,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TIE_2",
      "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature2",
      "shortName" : "Tie2",
      "sensorValue" : 20.7,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 6,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TIE_2_DERIVAATTA",
      "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature2change",
      "shortName" : "DTie2",
      "sensorValue" : -0.4,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C/h"
    }, {
      "id" : 7,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "MAA_1",
      "oldName" : "groundtemperature1",
      "shortName" : "Maa1",
      "sensorValue" : 21.4,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 8,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "MAA_2",
      "oldName" : "groundtemperature2",
      "shortName" : "Maa2",
      "sensorValue" : 21.7,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 9,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KASTEPISTE",
      "oldName" : "dewpoint",
      "shortName" : "KastP",
      "sensorValue" : 14.5,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 10,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "JAATYMISPISTE_1",
      "oldName" : "freezingpoint1",
      "shortName" : "JääPi1",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 11,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "JAATYMISPISTE_2",
      "oldName" : "freezingpoint2",
      "shortName" : "JääPi2",
      "sensorValue" : -0.1,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 16,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KESKITUULI",
      "oldName" : "averagewindspeed",
      "shortName" : "KTuuli",
      "sensorValue" : 1.5,
      "sensorUnit" : "m/s"
    }, {
      "id" : 18,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TUULENSUUNTA",
      "oldName" : "winddirection",
      "shortName" : "TSuunt",
      "sensorValue" : 97.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "°"
    }, {
      "id" : 21,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "ILMAN_KOSTEUS",
      "oldName" : "humidity",
      "shortName" : "Koste",
      "sensorValue" : 79.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "%"
    }, {
      "id" : 22,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SADE",
      "oldName" : "precipitation",
      "shortName" : "Sade",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "///",
      "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Pouta",
      "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry weather"
    }, {
      "id" : 23,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SADE_INTENSITEETTI",
      "oldName" : "precipitationintensity",
      "shortName" : "S-Int",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "mm/h"
    }, {
      "id" : 24,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SADESUMMA",
      "oldName" : "precipitationsum",
      "shortName" : "S-Sum",
      "sensorValue" : 0.3,
      "sensorUnit" : "mm"
    }, {
      "id" : 25,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SATEEN_OLOMUOTO_PWDXX",
      "oldName" : "precipitationtype",
      "shortName" : "S-Olom",
      "sensorValue" : 7.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "///",
      "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Pouta",
      "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry weather"
    }, {
      "id" : 26,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "NAKYVYYS",
      "oldName" : "visibility",
      "shortName" : "Näk_km",
      "sensorValue" : 2.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "km"
    }, {
      "id" : 27,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KELI_1",
      "oldName" : "roadsurfaceconditions1",
      "shortName" : "Keli1",
      "sensorValue" : 1.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "***",
      "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Kuiva",
      "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry"
    }, {
      "id" : 28,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KELI_2",
      "oldName" : "roadsurfaceconditions2",
      "shortName" : "Keli2",
      "sensorValue" : 1.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "***",
      "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Kuiva",
      "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry"
    }, {
      "id" : 29,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "VAROITUS_1",
      "oldName" : "warning1",
      "shortName" : "Varo1",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "???",
      "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "OK",
      "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "OK"
    }, {
      "id" : 30,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "VAROITUS_2",
      "oldName" : "warning2",
      "shortName" : "Varo2",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "???",
      "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "OK",
      "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "OK"
    }, {
      "id" : 31,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "JOHTAVUUS_1",
      "oldName" : "conductivity1",
      "shortName" : "Joht1",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "V"
    }, {
      "id" : 32,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "JOHTAVUUS_2",
      "oldName" : "conductivity2",
      "shortName" : "Joht2",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "V"
    }, {
      "id" : 33,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "PINTASIGNAALI_1",
      "oldName" : "surfacesignal1",
      "shortName" : "PSig1",
      "sensorValue" : 1.5,
      "sensorUnit" : "V"
    }, {
      "id" : 34,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "PINTASIGNAALI_2",
      "oldName" : "surfacesignal2",
      "shortName" : "PSig2",
      "sensorValue" : 2.3,
      "sensorUnit" : "V"
    }, {
      "id" : 35,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "JAATAAJUUS_1",
      "oldName" : "icefrequency1",
      "shortName" : "JTaaj1",
      "sensorValue" : 115.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "Hz"
    }, {
      "id" : 36,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "JAATAAJUUS_2",
      "oldName" : "icefrequency2",
      "shortName" : "JTaaj2",
      "sensorValue" : 393.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "Hz"
    }, {
      "id" : 49,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KASTEPISTE_ERO_TIE",
      "oldName" : "roaddewpointdifference",
      "shortName" : "KpEroT",
      "sensorValue" : 6.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 50,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KOSTEUDEN_MAARA_1",
      "oldName" : "surfacemoisture1",
      "shortName" : "KosMä1",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "mm"
    }, {
      "id" : 51,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KOSTEUDEN_MAARA_2",
      "oldName" : "surfacemoisture2",
      "shortName" : "KosMä2",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "mm"
    }, {
      "id" : 52,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SUOLAN_MAARA_1",
      "oldName" : "saltamount1",
      "shortName" : "SuoMä1",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "g/m2"
    }, {
      "id" : 53,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SUOLAN_MAARA_2",
      "oldName" : "saltamount2",
      "shortName" : "SuoMä2",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "g/m2"
    }, {
      "id" : 54,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SUOLAN_VAKEVYYS_1",
      "oldName" : "saltconcentration1",
      "shortName" : "SuoVä1",
      "sensorValue" : 252.6,
      "sensorUnit" : "g/l"
    }, {
      "id" : 55,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "SUOLAN_VAKEVYYS_2",
      "oldName" : "saltconcentration2",
      "shortName" : "SuoVä2",
      "sensorValue" : 391.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "g/l"
    }, {
      "id" : 56,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TURVALLISUUSLAMPO_1",
      "oldName" : "safetytemperature1",
      "shortName" : "TurLä1",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 57,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "TURVALLISUUSLAMPO_2",
      "oldName" : "safetytemperature2",
      "shortName" : "TurLä2",
      "sensorValue" : -0.1,
      "sensorUnit" : "°C"
    }, {
      "id" : 58,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "NAKYVYYS_METRIA",
      "oldName" : "visibilitymeters",
      "shortName" : "Näky_m",
      "sensorValue" : 2000.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "m"
    }, {
      "id" : 98,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "AURINKOUP",
      "oldName" : "sunup",
      "shortName" : "Aurink",
      "sensorValue" : 1.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "???"
    }, {
      "id" : 99,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "VALOISAA",
      "oldName" : "bright",
      "shortName" : "Valoa?",
      "sensorValue" : 1.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "???"
    }, {
      "id" : 100,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "VALLITSEVA_SAA",
      "oldName" : "VALLITSEVA_SAA",
      "shortName" : "Säätila",
      "sensorValue" : 81.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "///"
    }, {
      "id" : 130,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KUITUVASTE_PIENI_1",
      "oldName" : "fiberresponsesmall1",
      "shortName" : "KVaP1 ",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "###"
    }, {
      "id" : 131,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KUITUVASTE_PIENI_2",
      "oldName" : "fiberresponsesmall2",
      "shortName" : "KVaP2 ",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "###"
    }, {
      "id" : 132,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KUITUVASTE_SUURI_1",
      "oldName" : "fiberresponsebig1",
      "shortName" : "KVaS1 ",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "###"
    }, {
      "id" : 133,
      "roadStationId" : 2050,
      "name" : "KUITUVASTE_SUURI_2",
      "oldName" : "fiberresponsebig2",
      "shortName" : "KVaS2 ",
      "sensorValue" : 0.0,
      "sensorUnit" : "###"
    } ]
  } ]
}

var windDirection = 18;
var item  = json.weatherStations[0].sensorValues.find((i) => i.id== windDirection)


console.log(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is with [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Depending on your browser support needs, you may need to add the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) to add IE support.

```js
var response = {
  "dataUpdatedTime": "2017-07-11T15:47:00+03:00",
  "weatherStations": [{
    "id": 2050,
    "measuredTime": "2017-07-11T15:44:00+03:00",
    "sensorValues": [{
        "id": 1,
        "roadStationId": 2050,
        "name": "ILMA",
        "oldName": "airtemperature1",
        "shortName": "Ilma ",
        "sensorValue": 18.2,
        "sensorUnit": "°C"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "roadStationId": 2050,
        "name": "ILMA_DERIVAATTA",
        "oldName": "airtemperature1change",
        "shortName": "DIlm",
        "sensorValue": 0.2,
        "sensorUnit": "°C/h"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "roadStationId": 2050,
        "name": "TIE_1",
        "oldName": "roadsurfacetemperature1",
        "shortName": "Tie1 ",
        "sensorValue": 20.5,
        "sensorUnit": "°C"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "roadStationId": 2050,
        "name": "TIE_1_DERIVAATTA",
        "oldName": "roadsurfacetemperature1change",
        "shortName": "DTie1",
        "sensorValue": -0.2,
        "sensorUnit": "°C/h"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

//fat arrow if env supportd it
console.log(response.weatherStations[0].sensorValues.find( o => o.id === 3))

//without fat arrow
console.log(response.weatherStations[0].sensorValues.find( function (o) { return o.id === 3 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data={
  dataUpdatedTime: "2017-07-11T15:47:00+03:00",
  weatherStations: [
    {
      id: 2050,
      measuredTime: "2017-07-11T15:44:00+03:00",
      sensorValues: [
        {
          id: 1,
          roadStationId: 2050,
          name: "ILMA",
          oldName: "airtemperature1",
          shortName: "Ilma ",
          sensorValue: 18.2,
          sensorUnit: "°C"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          roadStationId: 2050,
          name: "ILMA_DERIVAATTA",
          oldName: "airtemperature1change",
          shortName: "DIlm",
          sensorValue: 0.2,
          sensorUnit: "°C/h"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          roadStationId: 2050,
          name: "TIE_1",
          oldName: "roadsurfacetemperature1",
          shortName: "Tie1 ",
          sensorValue: 20.5,
          sensorUnit: "°C"
        }   
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function findByName(name){
  return data.weatherStations[0].sensorValues.filter((item)=>item.name==name);
}

console.log(findByName('ILMA'))
```

Comment: @Shafizadeh yes my account uxuiitten

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.filter()`, such as:

```
test[0].weatherStations[0].sensorValues.filter((item)=>{
    return (item.id == 18)
})
```

Example:

```js
    let test = [{
      "dataUpdatedTime" : "2017-07-11T15:47:00+03:00",
      "weatherStations" : [ {
        "id" : 2050,
        "measuredTime" : "2017-07-11T15:44:00+03:00",
        "sensorValues" : [ {
          "id" : 1,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "ILMA",
          "oldName" : "airtemperature1",
          "shortName" : "Ilma ",
          "sensorValue" : 18.2,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 2,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "ILMA_DERIVAATTA",
          "oldName" : "airtemperature1change",
          "shortName" : "DIlm",
          "sensorValue" : 0.2,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C/h"
        }, {
          "id" : 3,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TIE_1",
          "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature1",
          "shortName" : "Tie1 ",
          "sensorValue" : 20.5,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 4,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TIE_1_DERIVAATTA",
          "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature1change",
          "shortName" : "DTie1",
          "sensorValue" : -0.2,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C/h"
        }, {
          "id" : 5,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TIE_2",
          "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature2",
          "shortName" : "Tie2",
          "sensorValue" : 20.7,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 6,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TIE_2_DERIVAATTA",
          "oldName" : "roadsurfacetemperature2change",
          "shortName" : "DTie2",
          "sensorValue" : -0.4,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C/h"
        }, {
          "id" : 7,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "MAA_1",
          "oldName" : "groundtemperature1",
          "shortName" : "Maa1",
          "sensorValue" : 21.4,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 8,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "MAA_2",
          "oldName" : "groundtemperature2",
          "shortName" : "Maa2",
          "sensorValue" : 21.7,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 9,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KASTEPISTE",
          "oldName" : "dewpoint",
          "shortName" : "KastP",
          "sensorValue" : 14.5,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 10,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "JAATYMISPISTE_1",
          "oldName" : "freezingpoint1",
          "shortName" : "JääPi1",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 11,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "JAATYMISPISTE_2",
          "oldName" : "freezingpoint2",
          "shortName" : "JääPi2",
          "sensorValue" : -0.1,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 16,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KESKITUULI",
          "oldName" : "averagewindspeed",
          "shortName" : "KTuuli",
          "sensorValue" : 1.5,
          "sensorUnit" : "m/s"
        }, {
          "id" : 18,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TUULENSUUNTA",
          "oldName" : "winddirection",
          "shortName" : "TSuunt",
          "sensorValue" : 97.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "°"
        }, {
          "id" : 21,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "ILMAN_KOSTEUS",
          "oldName" : "humidity",
          "shortName" : "Koste",
          "sensorValue" : 79.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "%"
        }, {
          "id" : 22,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SADE",
          "oldName" : "precipitation",
          "shortName" : "Sade",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "///",
          "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Pouta",
          "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry weather"
        }, {
          "id" : 23,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SADE_INTENSITEETTI",
          "oldName" : "precipitationintensity",
          "shortName" : "S-Int",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "mm/h"
        }, {
          "id" : 24,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SADESUMMA",
          "oldName" : "precipitationsum",
          "shortName" : "S-Sum",
          "sensorValue" : 0.3,
          "sensorUnit" : "mm"
        }, {
          "id" : 25,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SATEEN_OLOMUOTO_PWDXX",
          "oldName" : "precipitationtype",
          "shortName" : "S-Olom",
          "sensorValue" : 7.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "///",
          "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Pouta",
          "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry weather"
        }, {
          "id" : 26,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "NAKYVYYS",
          "oldName" : "visibility",
          "shortName" : "Näk_km",
          "sensorValue" : 2.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "km"
        }, {
          "id" : 27,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KELI_1",
          "oldName" : "roadsurfaceconditions1",
          "shortName" : "Keli1",
          "sensorValue" : 1.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "***",
          "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Kuiva",
          "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry"
        }, {
          "id" : 28,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KELI_2",
          "oldName" : "roadsurfaceconditions2",
          "shortName" : "Keli2",
          "sensorValue" : 1.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "***",
          "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "Kuiva",
          "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "Dry"
        }, {
          "id" : 29,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "VAROITUS_1",
          "oldName" : "warning1",
          "shortName" : "Varo1",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "???",
          "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "OK",
          "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "OK"
        }, {
          "id" : 30,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "VAROITUS_2",
          "oldName" : "warning2",
          "shortName" : "Varo2",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "???",
          "sensorValueDescriptionFi" : "OK",
          "sensorValueDescriptionEn" : "OK"
        }, {
          "id" : 31,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "JOHTAVUUS_1",
          "oldName" : "conductivity1",
          "shortName" : "Joht1",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "V"
        }, {
          "id" : 32,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "JOHTAVUUS_2",
          "oldName" : "conductivity2",
          "shortName" : "Joht2",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "V"
        }, {
          "id" : 33,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "PINTASIGNAALI_1",
          "oldName" : "surfacesignal1",
          "shortName" : "PSig1",
          "sensorValue" : 1.5,
          "sensorUnit" : "V"
        }, {
          "id" : 34,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "PINTASIGNAALI_2",
          "oldName" : "surfacesignal2",
          "shortName" : "PSig2",
          "sensorValue" : 2.3,
          "sensorUnit" : "V"
        }, {
          "id" : 35,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "JAATAAJUUS_1",
          "oldName" : "icefrequency1",
          "shortName" : "JTaaj1",
          "sensorValue" : 115.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "Hz"
        }, {
          "id" : 36,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "JAATAAJUUS_2",
          "oldName" : "icefrequency2",
          "shortName" : "JTaaj2",
          "sensorValue" : 393.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "Hz"
        }, {
          "id" : 49,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KASTEPISTE_ERO_TIE",
          "oldName" : "roaddewpointdifference",
          "shortName" : "KpEroT",
          "sensorValue" : 6.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 50,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KOSTEUDEN_MAARA_1",
          "oldName" : "surfacemoisture1",
          "shortName" : "KosMä1",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "mm"
        }, {
          "id" : 51,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KOSTEUDEN_MAARA_2",
          "oldName" : "surfacemoisture2",
          "shortName" : "KosMä2",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "mm"
        }, {
          "id" : 52,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SUOLAN_MAARA_1",
          "oldName" : "saltamount1",
          "shortName" : "SuoMä1",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "g/m2"
        }, {
          "id" : 53,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SUOLAN_MAARA_2",
          "oldName" : "saltamount2",
          "shortName" : "SuoMä2",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "g/m2"
        }, {
          "id" : 54,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SUOLAN_VAKEVYYS_1",
          "oldName" : "saltconcentration1",
          "shortName" : "SuoVä1",
          "sensorValue" : 252.6,
          "sensorUnit" : "g/l"
        }, {
          "id" : 55,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "SUOLAN_VAKEVYYS_2",
          "oldName" : "saltconcentration2",
          "shortName" : "SuoVä2",
          "sensorValue" : 391.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "g/l"
        }, {
          "id" : 56,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TURVALLISUUSLAMPO_1",
          "oldName" : "safetytemperature1",
          "shortName" : "TurLä1",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 57,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "TURVALLISUUSLAMPO_2",
          "oldName" : "safetytemperature2",
          "shortName" : "TurLä2",
          "sensorValue" : -0.1,
          "sensorUnit" : "°C"
        }, {
          "id" : 58,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "NAKYVYYS_METRIA",
          "oldName" : "visibilitymeters",
          "shortName" : "Näky_m",
          "sensorValue" : 2000.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "m"
        }, {
          "id" : 98,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "AURINKOUP",
          "oldName" : "sunup",
          "shortName" : "Aurink",
          "sensorValue" : 1.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "???"
        }, {
          "id" : 99,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "VALOISAA",
          "oldName" : "bright",
          "shortName" : "Valoa?",
          "sensorValue" : 1.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "???"
        }, {
          "id" : 100,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "VALLITSEVA_SAA",
          "oldName" : "VALLITSEVA_SAA",
          "shortName" : "Säätila",
          "sensorValue" : 81.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "///"
        }, {
          "id" : 130,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KUITUVASTE_PIENI_1",
          "oldName" : "fiberresponsesmall1",
          "shortName" : "KVaP1 ",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "###"
        }, {
          "id" : 131,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KUITUVASTE_PIENI_2",
          "oldName" : "fiberresponsesmall2",
          "shortName" : "KVaP2 ",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "###"
        }, {
          "id" : 132,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KUITUVASTE_SUURI_1",
          "oldName" : "fiberresponsebig1",
          "shortName" : "KVaS1 ",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "###"
        }, {
          "id" : 133,
          "roadStationId" : 2050,
          "name" : "KUITUVASTE_SUURI_2",
          "oldName" : "fiberresponsebig2",
          "shortName" : "KVaS2 ",
          "sensorValue" : 0.0,
          "sensorUnit" : "###"
        } ]
      } ]
    }];
    
    console.log(test[0].weatherStations[0].sensorValues.filter((item)=>{
      return (item.id == 18)
    }));
```

It will return the Object containing that ID.